# Showing off some related [M]SOF coding

Tags: discussion, support, api, screen-scraping

After some previous questions about polite scraping('s), etc. I wrapped up work on a three site, 50 newest questions display grid. Would it be all right to ask for some peer review of it on Meta Stack Overflow?

<strike>I will admit to borrowing the tag style design, but other than that I think it's pretty original, albeit rather bare bones at the moment.</strike>

Removed `:hover` expansion of the excerpt and tags.

[The page can be found here.](http://codebase.joshuakehn.com/homestead/)

I'm currently working with the API that's in beta mode. <strike>You can view that page [over here](http://codebase.unchartedmess.com/homestead/index.php/homestead/api). <strike>It's not fancy or even very functional,</strike> but it's a work in progress and way faster then scraping. *Update:* Well I had some spare time so I reformated it and styled it like the scrape. Scrape page is still up until they enable this beta API on the other sites (this one included).</strike> *API page is broken at the moment*

Tags are now supported with highlighting. Just type into the tag bar and find interesting tags across all three sites.

Comment: Just show it already.. we already know your going to anyway :P

Comment: Also, be sure you follow these rules http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/etiquette-of-screen-scraping-stack-overflow

Comment: @earlz: Link added.

Comment: I don't much like it... I usually twitch my mouse whenever I'm reading things and that completely messes up with your UI.

Comment: The tradeoff for that is not seeing the expanded excerpt. Is that a fair tradeoff?

Comment: You've got SF in the title, but not on the page, accidental?

Comment: It would be super simple to add, but right now the page is wide enough as it is and I don't follow SF much at all.

Comment: [now you're just being mean](http://localhost/projects/homestead/index.php/homestead/api) ...

Comment: @quack: What can I say, I'm a [tease](http://codebase.unchartedmess.com/homestead/index.php/homestead/api).

Comment: Is it "blinking" on cursor moves?

Comment: Not for me, no. It shouldn't "blink" anything either, except the background on the questions though.

Comment: @random: Let me know if it's still blinking, I updated some of the javascript just now.

Comment: No longer blinking/winking or whatever it was doing.

Comment: That's good, I figured it was because every 300ms I was clearing the interesting tags and redistributing them. Now it only does that if it changes.

Answer (score 2):

It looks very pretty!

You might be able to improve the back end by using API methods rather than screen-scraping -- s[ee here for more info](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/stack-overflow-api-private-beta-starts/).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will look into that (email sent!). Any other comments? Usability, styling, etc?