# HTTP 302 from /users?tab=moderators

Tags: support, http

While doing some data analysis I put together an application to pull the list of moderators for a site from `/users?tab=moderators` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)).

When I attempt to grab this page, either through my application or, for example, `wget`, I receive a 302 response directing back to `/users?tab=reputation&filter=all`.

Request:

```
GET /users?tab=moderators HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_55
Host: stackoverflow.com
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /users?tab=reputation&filter=all
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Guid: <redacted>
Set-Cookie: <redacted>
Date: Sun, 12 Apr 2015 20:41:18 GMT
Content-Length: 153

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/users?tab=reputation&amp;filter=all">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Why is this response being received, and what do I need to include in the request to avoid it? I do not run into this issue when directly requesting any other pages on the site, and I do not run into this issue visiting `/users?tab=moderators` in a browser (even when not logged in).

Comment: I'm not sure about the redirect, but [using the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/elected-moderators) for this would probably make more sense anyway.

Comment: @TimStone Yeah; the API would make more sense. My application is already well-equipped to parse HTML but not the API responses, and this particular action is an afterthought. I'm trying to reduce extra work, although it'd probably be faster at this point to just switch to the API instead of trying to solve the request issue.

Comment: ^ And I did just that. Still curious about the 302 though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The User Agent header needs love.

This curl statement works for me and returns the html content of the moderators page:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)" https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators
```

While using your User Agent:

```
curl -A "Java/1.7.0_55" https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/users?tab=reputation&amp;filter=all">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

returns a 302 with a Location header.

Only an SE developer can explain why they handle routes under /users differently when an [short user agent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288094/158100) is coming in. I do recall that if you scrape on SE it is [considered a good practice to include in your user agent who you are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/446/158100). For that reason I include the url to my MSE user profile in the User Agent. Adding your profile link does indeed resolve your issue as well.