# Is there any way to find out when a moderator was elected/appointed?

Tags: support, moderators

Is information about the date that a moderator of a site was elected (or appointed) publicly available anywhere, in a way that is accessible from an application?

I have looked in the following places:

- [The API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) (both `/moderators` and `/moderators/elected`): The date a user became a moderator doesn't seem to be available, only the initial account creation date is available.
- [The site profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13531/michael-myers): No info there; also checked activity tab to see if some marker event was left there but didn't see anything.
- [The network profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/7745/michael-myers?tab=accounts): No information there.
- [The moderator user list](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators): This does have information in a blurb under each users' name, however:

  - I am unable to access that programmatically right now due to [HTTP 302 from /users?tab=moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253237/http-302-from-userstab-moderators).
  - Even if I were able to access it, the resolution of the information is too low. For example, some say "Elected 2011", but there were two elections in 2011, so it is not possible to associate with a specific date. Appointed moderators do have a specific date shown, though.
- [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com): There is no related info in the `Users` table.
- [Election pages](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5): Information about *elected* moderators can be obtained by visiting each past election page, looking at the results, and piecing the info together. Appointed moderator info is not available this way. If  `/users?tab=moderators` were accessible, the blanks could be filled in from there. However, this is a bit complicated.

Is this information available anywhere else? How can I determine when a moderator became a moderator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were very close when you went to the moderator user list. It only says "Elected 20XX", but it is actually a link. When you click on it, it will bring you to the actual election that moderator was elected in.

Also, because you couldn't access that right now, you could go to the [Stack Exchange list of all moderators](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) and access the same information from there by clicking on "show details" next to the site you want then clicking on the "Elected 20XX".

For appointed moderators, it tells you the exact date the moderator was appointed on the moderators tab. I'm not sure how to get this info when you don't have access to that page, yet.

Comment: Whoa, that's a link; cool! But even cooler is the /about/moderators page, which I didn't even know existed. I've confirmed that I can access it, and while the method is a bit complex (follow elected moderator link and grab date, or parse date for appointed moderators, both available in the list on that page), at least it's in an easily parseable centralized location. It's essentially equivalent to /users?tab=moderators, with the added step of having to locate the site in the lists. I'm going to hold off accepting this for a bit to see if a more direct method surfaces. Thanks!!

Comment: That information is still somewhat inaccurate since it doesn't account for moderators that were brought up *after* the election due to additional demands. For example, I was not actually brought on as a moderator until July of 2013, even though the [election page](http://stackoverflow.com/election/4) lists me as one of the elected from March. cc @JasonC

Comment: @animuson That's interesting. What was the process there? Did they pull from the highest voted remaining candidates after the fact, figuring it was still close enough time to the previous election?

Comment: @animuson Hmm, interesting. I'll try to find another way to tell that then too.

Comment: @JasonC They re-run the results for the entire election with one additional slot available. And yeah, it had only been four months, and they were only replacing one moderator. Another election didn't make sense.